# What do you call a speaker who does not follow a standard pronunciation?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

As per [Wikipedia](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_speaker), a native speaker is the one who learned to speak the language as a part of childhood development either through his(her) family or because his(her) country of origin. Let's suppose, for instance that...

My family moved from a certain country to an English speaking country, no matter why. I was born and went to school there. In my day to day life, at home, in my community, etc. I frequently use a language other than English and I have different pronunciation than the standard English pronunciation. Just to emphasize the case: unfortunately, I couldn't or didn't want to extend my education from a basic education.

As per definition I am a native English speaker although my pronunciation is clearly different.

How can I target distinct range of speaker that has a language, in this case English speakers?

Sometime even if it's a subtly different pronunciation, you can tell that it's different and sometimes can guess where their parents come from.

Answer (score 2):

Such as person **speaks with an accent** (or **has an accent**). You could describe the situation further to be specific. Obviously, all speakers speak with their own accents, but the phrasing above implies that the accent is not that of a widespread dialect.

In your scenario, it is unlikely the person would speak with an accent. Usually people who learn a language at a young age and achieve native proficiency in it speak with no accent. (Where "no accent" means with an accent reflecting the dialect(s) they grew up speaking.)

Comment: It's not that unlikely. I moved away from my country. I am learning myself a new language (not English but still a Germanic language). The language I am learning, in my opinion, is quite difficult to pronounce. I meet a wide variety of people, but when practicing with different people, some of them has a strong accent. For instance, those from Turkey, although they have born here, they have a quite different accent. Now with my language level is really easy to tell. I have a clear example at hand, so not unlikely.

Comment: Is there any specific compound word to target a different speakers based on their accents because of immigration?
Let's suppose I am applying into a school teaching vacancy, English, and my accent is different from the standard. My pupils complain because, my accent is clearly different from the standard.

Comment: You seem to be looking for something along the lines of *accent discrimination*  or *accentism*, or more broadly *linguistic discrimination*. The English in your last comment is non-standard so if you are having trouble with applications and interviews, I am not convinced it's all due to your accent.

Comment: @JD2000 No, no... May be I didn't choose my words correctly. I am not having troubles to get a job. I am just curious on looking for a precise word. Sorry I cannot be clearer.

Comment: @SNR No it's my fault - you did say "let's suppose". I don't think there is much beyond what Mike has already suggested. You can say "speaks like an immigrant" but that has a definite undercurrent of racism / nationalism. You can also say "speaks with a foreign accent" to emphasise that you're not talking about a strong regional accent, but that's about it.